# Section Rotation

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, sectioning, vertical-alignment, rotating

[image]

How to type the part where the chapter is rotated with or without the shaded box, and then there is text right beside it? What I have so far

```
\begin{document}
\section*{\rotatebox{90}{Chapter 1}}
\begin{center}
Test Test Test\\
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\newcommand\Section[2][\reversemarginpar]{{%
  #1%
  \section*{\marginnote{\raisebox{-1.1\height}{\rotatebox{90}{#2}}}}}}

\begin{document}
\Section{Chapter 1}
Test Test Test

\newpage
\Section[]{Chapter 2}
Test Test Test

\end{document}
```

[image]